# How to know if there are sub items/nodes in an AdvancedDatagrid

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, mxml

To summarize: **How can I remove a node branch (level 1) if it has zero Data items? And in turn also remove Node at higher level 0 if it's sub items are (empty or have been) removed?**

After much searching on the internet I still need to know if how to find out if an `AdvancedDatagrid` or a "node" contains children. How to know if it's empty or has "something"?  With it, I will be able to filter it with my function.. (Expalined below):

Firstly I apologize for my bad english.

I have an `AdvancedDatagrid` with for `dataProvider` an `ArrayCollection`.
I use a `GroupingCollection2` to group my data in nodes.

I use a filterFunction on a `ICollectionView` of `dataProvider` of the `AdvancedDatagrid`. It works!

Example of my grouped data :

```
- Node level 0
  -- Node level 1
     ++ Data 1
     ++ Data 2
     ++ Data 3
  -- Node level 1
     ++ Data 4
     ++ Data 5
- Node level 0
  -- Node level 1
     ++ Data 6
     ++ etc..
```

I filter only the data which are on "leafs" (**Data** sub nodes). After my filter function, **Data** items are correctly filtered!

Example of results after filtering these: **Data 2**, **Data 4**, **Data 5**, **Data 6** :

```
- Node level 0
  -- Node level 1
     ++ Data 1
     ++ Data 3
  -- Node level 1

- Node level 0
  -- Node level 1
```

For example nodes with "unwanted" **Data** are correctly filtered out.

BUT I want to filter out those now "empty" nodes too!! Thats is to say **How can I remove a node branch (level 1) if it has zero leaf items? And in turn also remove a Node level 0 if it's total sub-branches are zero after they've been removed?**

I want this list :

```
- Node level 0
  -- Node level 1
     ++ Data 1
     ++ Data 3
```

Thank you in advance.

(ps: i'm available for questions if I was not enough specific)

Comment: Cant you just update/recreate the tree using only remaining items as input for new tree setup? I don't use Flex or MXML but isn't there a way to read a "node" length? (i.e will be zero if node is empty"). Anyways with that information you could try some `If/Else` statements. If Node is filtered then remove it from list of "nodes items" and update the tree. Or even If `Node_level_1` has no leafs (leaf.length == 0) then remove Node, If `Node_level_0` has no sub nodes then remove `Node_level_0`

Comment: After filtering.. the last 3 items shown is there really a space between `-- Node level 1` and `- Node level 0`? Like it's still holding an invisible slots for **++ Data 4** and **++ Data 5**? Hopefully someone more experienced can help

Comment: Exactly ! I'm looking for a way "to read a node length". It exists a way to do that but not with `GroupingCollection` or I don't know this way.. (thank u for corrections by the way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Well I figured it out finally !!!**

My secret is when I group data with `GroupingCollection2` I pass to the node grouped some news *(with a `groupingField`)*. But news are not showed by the itemRenderer of the node. 
And with a system of `substring` on these news I use them in my `filterFucntion`.

**Explanations about difference between "basic" grouping and my grouping :**
In fact when you group data, created nodes contain only the field whereby they've been created.

**For instance** my data have 4 fiels : domain, test, status, version.
I group them by domain & by test like this *(it's a example of how my data are showed, with an item renderer different for each level)*.

**BEFORE DATA WERE LIKE THAT:**

```
- domain 1
  -- test 1
     ++ status/version 1
     ++ status/version 2
  -- test 2
     ++ status/version 3
     ++ status/version 4
- domain 2 etc..
```

**But** on the leafs (++ rows), after grouping, there is yet data of the fields "grouped". Namely test and domain field!

**For summary after basic grouping:**

- data in node level 0 : domain
- data in node level 1 : test
- data in leaf level 2 : domain / test / status / version.

**After my grouping data showed are the same.**

**BUT**

**After my grouping:**

- data in node level 0 : domain
- data in node level 1 : domain / test
- data in leaf level 2 : domain / test / status / version.

Thanks to that I can with my filter function (using substring system) know the parent of each node and by the same occasion if the node is empty after a filter!

**I think I'm not clear at all and I apologize.. It's really complex so I'm ready to answer to more specific questions if someone meet a similar problem !!**